# Set Factor Reference Level Upon Creation

Tags: r

Is there a way to create a factor variable in R and simultaneously specify *just* the reference level for that factor?

I can accomplish this in two steps, first creating the factor, then using `relevel()`, e.g.

```
MyVar = factor(seq(1, 10))
MyVar = relevel(MyVar, ref = 5)
```

Or, I can do it in a single step, using the `levels =` argument of the `factor()` function.  But, that requires first getting a list of all unique values of the factor and then putting the desired level first, which in turn will usually then require an additional couple of steps.

It seems like this should be a pretty basic functionality, but I can't seem to find a way to accomplish it.  Is it just not possible directly in R?

Comment: Why can't `relevel(factor(seq(1, 10)), ref = 5)` not work

Comment: Code should be readable, not "golfy". Having an extra line for setting a reference should get you through the gates of heaven.

Comment: I agree with @RomanLuštrik, 6 months from now, if you are going to read the same command and if it requires 4-5 minutes to understand what is going on is not better\

Comment: Yeah, I guess, but I would have thought that the `factor()` function would take `ref = ` as an argument, or that there would be a way to specify just a single value for `levels = `.  I sure don't see why that should be at all difficult to read.  So, I wondered if I had overlooked something along those lines, or if there were some other kind of relatively simple way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A flexible option would be to use `fct_relevel` from `forcats` where we can place the level anywhere

```
library(forcats)
fct_relevel(factor(seq(1, 10)), '5')
#[1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#Levels: 5 1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 10
```

Suppose, if the `level` should be `after` 2

```
fct_relevel(factor(seq(1, 10)), '5', after = 2)
#[1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#Levels: 1 2 5 3 4 6 7 8 9 10
```

---

Also, as stated in the comments, it can be done in a single step with `relevel` as well

```
relevel(factor(seq(1, 10)), ref = 5)
```